# javascript regexp - replace all floating point numbers in a string with rounded numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

Kind of basic javascript/regexp yet i just cant get it together right now.

I have a string with floating point numbers

```
"m 135.969098800748,207.1229911216347 c -0.7762491582645,-0.2341987326806  -1.1870973239185,-1.1248369132174 -1.6826107603382,-1.6767899650268 z"
```

and i want to replace all floating point numbers with rounded numbers (Math.round)

```
"m 136,207 c -1,0  1,-1 -2,-2 z"
```

How to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.replace` and a callback.

```
var str = "m 135.969098800748,207.1229911216347 c -0.7762491582645,-0.2341987326806  -1.1870973239185,-1.1248369132174 -1.6826107603382,-1.6767899650268 z";
str.replace(/-?\d+\.\d+/g, function(x) {
  return Math.round(parseFloat(x));
})

=> "m 136,207 c -1,0  -1,-1 -2,-2 z"
```

Btw, there's a typo in your expected result, you're missing a `-`

```
"m 136,207 c -1,0  1,-1 -2,-2 z"
```

should be

```
"m 136,207 c -1,0  -1,-1 -2,-2 z"
```

and my code above gives the correct result.