# Compound Replace of Floating Point Number with Double Quotes

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I have a problem with JSON strings flowing back and forth between PHP and javascript Ajax calls.  The PHP routines are sending JSON encoded strings without quotes around the floating point numbers, i.e.

```
{"Route_1":[{"lat":-31.526107395574975,"lng":146.31591796875},{"lat":-31.51674215813217,"lng":145.5303955078125}]}}
```

But when the JSON string is received by the ajax routine, all the floating point numbers have double quotes around them as shown here:

```
{"Route_1":[{"lat":"-31.526107395574975","lng":"146.31591796875"},{"lat":"-31.51674215813217","lng":"145.5303955078125"}]}
```

So after a couple of days trying to get to the bottom of it, I have decided the best course of action is just to parse this to remove the double quotes.   I can identify the floating point numbers and using [.replace and callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877500/javascript-regexp-replace-all-floating-point-numbers-in-a-string-with-rounded).  but the compound replace is not working as I would expect it to - that is it is just returning the same string.

Can anyone shed some light on this please?  btw this is not the same issue as asking [how to parse a JSON string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398091/how-to-parse-a-jsonarray-and-convert-in-javascript)

```js
var str = '{"Route_1":[{"lat":"-31.526107395574975","lng":"146.31591796875"},{"lat":"-31.51674215813217","lng":"145.5303955078125"}]}'

var regex = /[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/g;

var t = str.replace(regex, function(x) {
  return x.replace(/"/g, "");
})

console.log(t);
```

Comment: Why would you use regex when you have a perfectly servicable JSON you can convert to an object and then manipulate?

Comment: Although it actually seems that _isn't_ valid JSON. However, my point stands - you want to do stuff with JSON - if you had one that is valid, you shouldn't need to regex it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a JSONArray and convert in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398091/how-to-parse-a-jsonarray-and-convert-in-javascript)

Comment: All my transfers are in JSON.  On the server side the code '$jsonArray =  json_encode( $json );' transfers the correct file but once on the client side the quotes are introduced - it has just proved too time consuming to try to untangle it.

Comment: The `str` parameter you have does not hold correct JSON as it is also quoting each object in the array. However, the _values_ in object being quoted is a trivial thing to change _correctly_ when you properly convert the JSON into a JavaScript object, as the linked question shows. It turns your question from "how do I regex this" to "how do I convert a string into a number" which is far safer, far easier and far better defined. Using a regex is both unnecessary and brittle, which makes it the wrong approach. Regex a golden hammer is not.

Comment: I fully agree with you regarding the soundness of staying within a particular environment, but when that environment is introducing all sorts of artefacts (PHP backslashes ) and double quotes your ability to fathom some reasoning and workarounds is difficult and is possible just as bad as introducing post processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to match `"` as well in the regex. Check below update.

```js
var str = '{"Route_1":[{"lat":"-31.526107395574975","lng":"146.31591796875"},{"lat":"-31.51674215813217","lng":"145.5303955078125"}]}';

var regex = /\"[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\"/g;

var t = str.replace(regex, function(x) {
  return x.replace(/"/g, "");
})

console.log(t);
```

Comment: 1. I disagree that regex is the correct tool for the job here. 2. That's still not correct JSON.

Comment: I am sorry for the error in the JSON.  I will correct it above.  The syntax error crept in when I was testing the JSON strings being sent from the client.  I was using double quotes to see if that was causing the problem.  The correct JSON is now shown.  Thanks