# Replace floating number in a string

Tags: javascript, replace

I want to replace a floating number by another one in my string using Javascript.

Examples:

```
var string1 = '$10.50';
var string2 = '$10.50 USD';
var string3 = '10.50 €';
```

Results:

```
var newFloatNb = 15.99;

string1 = '$15.99';
string2 = '$15.99 USD';
string3 = '15.99 €';
```

Anyway to do this? I want to keep the currencies that are not always the same.

Comment: @Nexevis No, price could be higher. Example $150.99 USD

Comment: so reg exp to match a number and replace.....

Comment: Find the number by using a regex (/[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g) and then replace it.

Comment: 300 rep should be enough for you to know that you should post your attempt if you expect someone to help you fix it.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't thought of that, probably tired.... I'll do it by extracting the number

Comment: why not try to use Regex, see below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877500/javascript-regexp-replace-all-floating-point-numbers-in-a-string-with-rounded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it, sorry for this question.

```
var string = '$10.50 USD';
var newFloatNb = 15.99;
var stringNumber = parseFloat(string.match(/-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)/)[0]).toFixed(2);
string = string.replace(stringNumber, '15.99');

console.log(string);
```

Comment: Note: if there are no numbers in your string, `string.match` will return undefined and your code will break (trying to access `[0]` of `undefined`). If this is a possibility, make sure to store your match in a separate variable and check the result before using it.